# Is there a simple way to AUTOMATE adding a program to the start menu and pin to taskbar

Tags: taskbar, start-menu

To clarify, this is different than all the other similar questions for several reasons. For one, I'm building a program that is supposed to be compatible with Win7-Win11 and so I need the tool I build for this to be compatible with all versions, so I need an older Win7 method this still works on newer versions of Windows. Normally I would do this with an installer, but I still need a way for zip installers to register shortcuts easily. No right clicking and pinning to taskbar, no dragging and dropping to the start menu. The process must be fully automated and can't use absolute paths. Sounds simple but Microsoft keeps changing things, I might need to use different methods for each OS and filter with an if/else statement, but I hope not. Also, were not relying on PowerShell since not all Win7 versions have it installed.

EDIT1: So I managed to pin to taskbar using pttb.exe and I verified simply copying the shortcut to AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs works on Win7-Win11 for adding to the regular Start Menu items. Only thing left to figure out is pinning to the Start Menu in the pinned section. I tried copying the shortcut to AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu but it didn't work, I suspect there's a registry entry for this.

Comment: You might look into using the [windows scripting host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/admin-development/create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh).  It should still work in Windows 11.  It's very simple as far as programming languages are concerned.  You can write VBS or JS code (I use JS only) to access objects that will make it easy.  [Here](https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/wsh/wshshell-specialfolders.html) is a list of the "special folders".  It's possible to be disabled but I don't think that is the default.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

Consider using one of the many application installer tools, which provide a simple scripting language and user interface for creating an installation package for your application. For example, the tool might check the operating system version and make adding to the Start Menu simple -- perhaps adding user options for Desktop and/or Start Menu shortcuts. Free, open-source [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page) has been one of my favorites; [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is also free and open-source and widely used, and there are [many others](https://alternativeto.net/software/actual-installer/).

See [this in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629393/is-it-possible-to-pin-to-start-menu-using-inno-setup) on using Inno Setup to pin to taskbar and [this, also in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326685/pin-icons-to-taskbar), on doing the same in NSIS.

One of the advantages in using these tools is providing a consistent, professional-looking installation experience... as well as avoiding the necessity of reinventing the wheel.